# Going to a specific line in a word doc from excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm writing a macro which pastes graphs from an excel file into word.

```
Worksheets(worksheetname).Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartname).Activate
Selection.Cut
mydoc.Activate
```

with worksheetname etc declared and defined correctly.

I have no idea how to refer to a line in a word document from within excel VBA. I have refer to a line in the document, I can paste it in.

edit:To clarify, I can paste into a paragraph in word. I'm looking to specify the location better than the beginning of the paragraph: either in a specific line, or specifying the end of the paragraph. /edit

My only ideas are:

```
Rng = mydoc.Range(doc.Paragraphs(1).Start, mydoc.Paragraphs(1).End - 1).paste
```

but I think that is in word-style VBA, which doesn't seem to work.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you trying to paste after a particular paragraph? in any doc? or insert to a particular point in a predefined template?  doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Paste() doesn't work?

Comment: I'm trying to paste at the end of a particular paragraph. I will edit my original post to reflect this.

doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Paste() pastes at the beginning of a paragraph.  I want to paste at the end / in a given line.

Comment: Line is a vague and misleading concept when working with word. This is because the lines change very often upon any insertion, font change, page setup, formatting etc... I suggest you drop completely the idea of "specific line". Reasoning in terms of paragraph is all right, as in the post, but not the title.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = d.Paragraphs(i).Range
r.Start = r.End
r.Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution to this which I think works pretty well.

It actually looks for the first word in the document and then goes down the amount of lines you want it to.

```
Sub LineSelection()

    Dim WordApp As Object

    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True

    ActiveDocument.Content.Select

    With Word.Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[Type very first word of the Word Document here]"
    End With

    If Word.Selection.Find.Execute Then
        Word.Selection.Select
        Word.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=3
        ''instead of [3] type the line you want to go to       >>>     ^^^
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope you find this solution helpfull.

And I am sorry I might be 2,5 years late with this ;)

Comment: I'm afraid it's too late for me Mateo, but thank you for this solution - I hope it helps people going forwards.